Unable to pair and bond 30 sensors with Ubuntu Server 20.04.6 LTS
We are developing a solution wherein we are trying to obtain data from between 30-35 sensors over BLE which will be paired and bonded with our device. The details of our devices(hardware wise) are as follows-
SBC - AL253 board from DFI based on Intel Atom E3900 Series
RAM - 2GB
OS - Ubuntu Server 20.04.6 LTS
We have developed an Application that communicates with the BLE adapter through DBus(version 1.12.16) and BlueZ (version 5.66).
The way our application works is we have registered DBus callbacks to determine RSSI property changes of an advertising sensors and based off of that we proceed to connect and carry out other activities. The problem we are facing is after 15 sensors get paired and bonded, the callbacks don't get invoked for the remaining sensors when they are advertising, but the callbacks for the 15 sensors that were paired are invoked properly and required operations work as intended.
We are unable to figure out as to why this is happening.
We deployed the same code with the exact same configurations on Lubuntu 20.04 and observed across multiple runs that we are able to get all the sensors paired and bonded without any issues. It is required by us to implement the application on Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS and any ideas/ suggestions towards understanding and solving this issue would be appreciated.
Thank you in advance.
NOTE : Please note that we are not trying to get multiple peripheral devices connected at the same time.

FYI:  You're aware that Lubuntu 20.04 LTS (you tagged) was a flavor of Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and came with 3 years of supported life? (refer https://lubuntu.me/lubuntu-20-04-lts-end-of-life-and-current-support-statuses/ reaching the end of its three year supported life) with 5 years applying to Ubuntu Desktop, Ubuntu Server, Ubuntu base but not flavors. You're still on-topic here with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS questions though (even if using LXQt)

Hi, I am aware that support for Lubuntu ended in April 2023, but I needed a lightweight alternative to check on the AL253 SBC, and that is also one of the reason why we are trying to get 30-35 devices paired and bonded on Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS instead of moving to Ubuntu.

Lubuntu 20.04.5 media (Lubuntu 20.04 LTS was EOL before 20.04.6 media was released thus why I'm mentioning 20.04.5) uses the HWE kernel stack, thus it differs for example with Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS Server media (which uses GA).. beyond just the desktop/app packages added by Lubuntu.  There are differences between desktop & server ISOs that may be key to your issue (given you mention 20.04 Server!) so did you explore those?

Check for System Limitations: Ubuntu Server might have a limit on the number of Bluetooth devices that can be paired at once. You can check this by running the command cat /proc/sys/kernel/pid_max. If the number is less than the number of sensors you are trying to connect, you might need to increase it.
Update Your System: Ensure your system is up-to-date with the latest patches and updates. Use the following commands to update your system:
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade

Update BlueZ: There might be a bug in the version of BlueZ you are using. Try updating to the latest version with the following commands:
sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends bluetooth

Also you can get more information about this using debugging tools like btmon and bluetoothcl
Hoping this may work

This isn't from ChatGPT or ChatAI?
